# theoretical foundations of gnuplot csplines

Tags: gnuplot

Which is the theoretical method employed in the csplines smoothing algorithm available in gnuplot? Is it a piecewise least square fit with polynomials? Like a Savitzky–Golay smoothing filter or, as the name suggests, some modification of bsplines? Also: in gnuplot version 4.4 I observed an oscillatory behaviour in the interpolating curve if I employ it for double-logarithmic plots. Is that to be expected?

Comment: What is unclear about the description in the manual?

Answer (score 0):

`csplines` stands for a cubic spline algorithm.  You can see this by typing `help csplines` in gnuplot, or by looking at the source code (see the functions `gen_cubic_spline` and `intp_cubic_spline` in `contour.c`).

About the oscillations in cubic splines (they are to be expected in some circumstances), see [this reference](http://www.korf.co.uk/spline.pdf), or [this](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0010448583900854) if you can access it.

Comment: I awarded the bounty so the points are not lost. I didnt find time to react to this answer in an adequate way.